# Cant load a local PDF File to webview

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am trying to load an PDF file that is in my xcode project to a web view I was using this code in `ViewDidLoad`

```
var pdfLoc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Anteproyecto", ofType:"pdf")!)
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfLoc!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Yesterday it worked but today it crsahes and displays this error in the logs

```
DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.
```

What Im I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "pdf")
var targetURL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest.requestWithURL(targetURL)
self.webView.loadRequest(request)
```

I hope it would work.

Comment: Please try to debug that a pdf file exists on  path or not. To do so get the path return from path variable and go to finder Go->Go to Folder.